# Continue task execution in background

Tags: iphone, ios4, multitasking

Am I missing something here with Multitasking feature. I know we can execute a task in background, but what I really need is that task continues execution when app goes in background. So what I need is different than starting a new task in background. If images are being loaded in a view and user presses the home button to make the app go in background, I want that images continue to load and when user makes the app active again, he can see all the loaded images. How can this be done? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Documentation on background task execution is on Apple's site in the [iPhone Application Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html).

Comment: I have already gone through that page. What I don't understand is can we continue a task which was already running when the app was in Forground? I don't want to start a task when app goes in background as the documentation suggests, I want my current task to keep executing even when app changes from foreground to background.

Comment: Alex I now realise that beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: can also be used before app enters background. Although I couldn't find any such sample. I think if we use it when app is still active, task will continue when app goes in background.

Answer (score 0):

According to mentioned documentation, if you use `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:` while in foreground, it will keep executing in background until it ends. Once that task has ended, your application is eligible to be suspended.